# Bind onClick event to a .click function

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have an image that I want to execute a link with a javascript onClick event when the image is clicked.

The link is:

```
<a class="test" href="javascript:;" onclick="foo.add( 'name=name', 'quantity=1' );">
<img src="pic.png" alt="Click" /></a>
```

Jquery I am fiddling with

```
$('.test').click(function(){
onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
$(this).attr('onclick','');
    return false;
});
```

Not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to just execute an already-existing onclick function, use something like this:

```
$('a.test img').click(function() {
  var link = $(this).parent()[0]
  var onclick = $(link).attr('onclick')
  onclick.call(link)
})
```

You want to pass the link into `onclick.call`.  That sets the link as the receiver of the function call, which is how the onclick attribute would normally fire.  If you simply call `onclick()`, you could run into trouble.

Comment: It seems to do the onClick event but I get an error that onclick is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error you're getting. Here's a jsfiddle permalink to the example I was working with. http://jsfiddle.net/BrsmE/ . Does that help?